# How to detect the version of Blackberry Messenger installed on a device from a Webworks App

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks, bb-messenger

I'm working on a BlackBerry WebWorks app that connects to the Blackberry Messenger Platform. However, a user's device must have at least BBM v6 before a webworks app can connect to the BBM platform on such device.

Now, the challenge is, I need to be able to know the version of BBM running on the user's device so I can display an appropriate message telling the user to upgrade if the user does not meet the BBM platform requirement.

How do I go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know the version of the `BBM` installed in the Device. Look at the **BBMProxyDemo** within the `BBM SDK` it shows how to get this info.
And you can also see this thread on supports forum

[How can i run the bbm integrated applicaiton in no bbm devices or below bbm 6.0 versions](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-can-i-run-the-bbm-integrated-applicaiton-in-no-bbm-devices/m-p/1403767#M181003)

Comment: Thanks or the response. I downloaded the BBM SDK Dependence Checker for BlackBerry WebWorks and followed the instructions. However, the manual does not tell you how to complete the proxy integration. They ended by saying save your project. I built both core application and proxy application. When I run the proxy application on a simulator, it says it can't find the core module and if I run the core application it gives me an error saying it can't run.

Comment: Thx...figured it out already. Had to build both applications and load them both into the device or simulator.